# Maclaurin Series of $\int_0^x \cos t^2\,dt$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin Series for $\int_{0}^{x}\cos t^2\,dt$.

$$\cos(x) = \sum\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2n!}$$

I'm trying this:

$$\cos^2 x = \sum\frac{(-1)^n x^{4n}}{(2n!)^2}$$

How would you solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that,

$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2n!}$$

Therefore,

$$\cos(t^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^{4n}}{2n!}$$

A power series can be integrated term by term. That is,

$$\int_{0}^{x}\cos(t^2)\,dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n!}\left(\int_{0}^{x}t^{4n}dt\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n!}\left(\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}\right)$$

Comment: I am confused why the denominator remains (2n)! instead of being square. Everything else is really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Well you know that, $\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ so to get, $\cos t^2$ we replace $x$ by $t^2$ and hence we get, $\cos(t^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n t^{4n}}{(2n)!}$