# How many solutions does equation $\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left( \frac{t^2}{3} \right) dt = 0$ have on the segment [0, 3]?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, integral-equations

The task i'm trying to solve is:

How many solutions (roots) does equation have:

$$\int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left( \frac{t^2}{3} \right) dt = 0$$

on the segment [0, 3] ?

By the moment i've found that cosine can be presented as series (the queston [Maclaurin Series of $\int_0^x \cos t^2\,dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610842/maclaurin-series-of-int-0x-cos-t2-dt) is about quite similar integral):

$$\cos(\frac{t^2}{3}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (\frac{t^2}{3})^{2n}}{2n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n {t}^{4n}}{9^n2n!} $$

So:

$$ \int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left( \frac{t^2}{3} \right) dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n!} \int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}}  \frac{t^{4n}}{9^n} dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{9^n2n!} \int\limits_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}}{t^{4n}}dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{9^n2n!} \frac{t^{4n+1}}{4n+1} \Biggr|_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} $$

Further fundamental theorem of calculus can be applied. 
But i'm stuck on the part related to the number of solutions on the segment.

Is the approach above correct to solve this kind of problem at all?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Taking a look at the plot, for all values $0\leq x \leq \frac{3}{2}$ the integral is strictly positive. Also if you look at the plot closer (and you can also prove this) you will see that the function cos is decreasing from 0 to 3. Thinking of the integral of this function in an interval of length 1/2, it should be positive up to the place where the function intersects 0, there should be a zero somewhere around there (it doesn't have to be exactly at the zero), and after that it stays being negative up to $x=3$. This is an informal view, but you should be able to prove there's only one zero.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the graph of $cos(\frac{t^2}{3})$.
[image]
This function is decreasing from $t=0$ up to some point $3+\varepsilon$ that you can compute. This means that the value
$$
\int_x^{x+\frac{1}{2}}cos(\frac{t^2}{3})dt
$$
is decreasing from $0$ to $\frac{5}{2}+\varepsilon$. It is obvious (and can be proven by the positivity/negativity of $cos(\frac{t^2}{3})$) that at $x=0$ the integral is positive, at $x=\frac{5}{2}+\varepsilon$ it is negative, and it is continuous in x, so there will be one zero. Due to monotonicity (it is decreasing) that zero will be the only zero in the interval. After that, in the part with $x= \frac{5}{2}+\varepsilon$ up to $x=3$ the integral stays strictly negative so there will be no additional zeroes.

All of these properties have to be proven, I have just given an informal proof using the graph of the function, but it should help to move you in the right direction.